# Data inaccuracy

Tags: database, oracle, math

In my new job we have an old program that is 10 to 15 years old I think, but is still used. I work on renewing the system which have a major problem in the old data.

The program is part of a payment system. It allows the original payment to be split at the paying time.

When it splits the payment it updates the original record and keeps the original date on the new record. It keeps the original value of the last operation in a separate field.

1000$ original split into 2 500$ --> by adding new 500$ record and updating the original into 500$ payment keeping 1000$ as the original.

500$ split into 300$ , 200$ --> by adding new 200$ record and updating the original row into 300$ payment, now the original is updated to 500$ instead of 1000$.

and so on.

The following image contains a example case based on a real case. with two original payments 1000 and 600.

[image: Example]

Whoever made the program did not use transactions, so some times the new record is not added (that's how the problem was discovered, but too late 15 years too late).

How can I find the affected customers in an 4.5 million records?

Is there a way to find the real original amount from the original field in the image? (I know that the answer might be no).

The database is oracle and the program was developed on oracle forms.

Thank you.

edit : a step by step example in a spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I9jOlCeiVuGdNlgXpiF_-Ic0e-cqaalrpUCJIUM5oAk/edit?usp=sharing

The problem is that the date field does not keep time only date. if the customer made several translations in the same day the error becomes hard to detect. it can only be detected if the customer made only one transaction in the day, even then it has to be viewed case by case. That's hard for years of work. Unfortunately, maybe they will have to suffer a loss for bad programming.

I will provide all the table fields tomorrow for better understanding.
Thank you for the replies.

Comment: I don't completely understand the process of adding and updating rows. Can you explain the two examples step by step? When is a new row added and when does an old row get updated (maybe show snapshots of the database at different stages). But I guess you would need a rather sophisticated matching approach. And there might not be a unique solution. Which of the records can get missing?

Comment: both your examples have the same customer id. is that just because of anonymization? can one customer id have 2 such payment trees at the same time? i think this makes a big difference in difficulty of the task.

Comment: Thank you, a spreadsheet with step by step example was added as an edit.